# Pushing to GitLab container registry no longer works

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have previously created a Docker image on GitLab, consisting of just a Dockerfile and a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like this:

```
build_image:
  image: docker:git
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/user149408/ci-image-server:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/user149408/ci-image-server:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

This has worked on my previous project, created in early May 2020. The Container Registry for the project shows me an image, which I have since successfully used in various CI jobs.

Now I have tried to create a new project, again with just these two files. In `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have just changed the project name (the user name is the same for both).

Now the CI/CD pipeline fails at `docker push` with:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

The login is successful and the build completes.

After studying the GitLab docs, I also tried alternate authentication options, but each time I get the exact same behavior:

```
docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
docker login -u $CI_JOB_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

What is wrong here? Has GitLab changed anything about pushing to its container registry in the past 9 months? Am I missing some project setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Referencing a nonexistent resource will also result in `requested access to the resource is denied`.** Confusing, but probably logical somewhere under the hood (the token is valid for the current repo only, not for others, or the requested resource doesn’t exist and thus can’t have any permissions).

So, if you are getting this error for inexplicable reasons, double-check the name for hard-to-spot typos.

In this case, the GitLab repository was called `ci-images-server` and I was trying to push to `ci-image-server` instead.